# Smooth stopping of scrolling in viewPager

Tags: android, scroll, google-play, android-viewpager

Basically, the viewpager on the play store (aka the Android Market) and on the official launcher of Android works in a different way than the one found in the support library for this case, and I wish to get the same UI experience as there for scrolling between pages.

The situation is like this: when you touch the viewpager to scroll between the pages (and scroll a bit), and then you stop touching and quickly touch again, I get a different behavior:

- on the play store (and the official launcher) the scrolling animation stops and is kept in sync with the touch.
- on the support library the viewpager just stops the animation and jumps to the page that it was about to go to, no matter where you touched it.

How do I achieve the same functionality as the one on the play store and the official launcher?

Comment: You would probably have to extend `ViewPager` (or modify `onTouchEvent()`) and have the animation stop when it registers a new touch event in the middle of scrolling.

Comment: have you tested it out ? does it work well? care to put some code ?

Comment: I have not tried this myself, I'm just giving you an idea to try out,  based on what you posted and what I know of the Android SDK. Hence why this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: the official launcher doesn't use `ViewPager`, but customization of `ViewGroup`, which overrides `onTouch()` `onTouchEvent()`. Absolutely not the same as in `Play Store`

Comment: so both of them use a totally different view ? also , are you sure you've understand the problem i've written about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Android Playground](http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/) project has this smooth stopping scroll you are talking about.

To be more specific, check [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/source/browse/trunk/SwipeyTabsSample/src/net/peterkuterna/android/apps/swipeytabs/SwipeyTabs.java) custom "`View Pager`" class.